# VS2015 Xamarin.Android: Intellisense can't see Resource.designer.cs

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin.Android. My solution compiles and links fine, with no warnings or errors. It runs correctly on my target device.

However, Intellisense can't find the autogenerated Resource.designer.cs file (which provides all the resource ID constants for things like page design elements from .axml files, string resources, assets and so on).

If I have code like: `var button = FindView(Resource.Id.some_button);`, then in the edit window the "Resource" part will have a red underline, and if I mouse over it, I see: "The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context."

In the Output window, if I change the dropdown to show output from Intellisense, I see a line like:

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\dghenke\Downloads\Widget\Widget\Widget.Android\obj\Debug\designtime\Resource.Designer.cs'.
```

That path exists up to the Debug\ folder, but there is no designtime\ folder underneath.

Things I have tried:

- Closing and re-opening Visual Studio.
- "Clean Solution" followed by "Build Solution".
- Completely removing my source tree then fetching a fresh copy from source control.
- Checking my .csproj file to make sure that `<MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
  <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
  <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>`
   is in the first `<PropertyGroup>` element.
- Removing the `Resource.designer.cs` file from the project and re-adding it.

Things I have not tried (and would prefer to keep it that way): Creating a whole new solution from scratch then manually re-adding all my source files from the original.

Versions:

- Visual Studio Professional 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Xamarin 4.8.0.756
- Xamarin.Android 8.1.0.13

Comment: Some issues are related to `Resharper` (and other 3rd-party vsix/plugins), try disabling each one to test if they are causing the issue. Faced the same issue in some of the 2017 15.5.x preview releases (w/ no 3rd-party extensions, it just plain broken :-( Try searching/posting on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Comment: Have you tried to test this solution on another computer to check if this issue is related to your current solution or your VS? If this issue only occurs in this solution, please delete the hidden .vs folder under this solution store folder or create a new blank solution then add projects one by one to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: No Resharper (nor any other third-party plugins); it's vanilla VS plus Xamarin.VS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What finally worked for me was addding:

```
<AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>False</AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>
```

to the first `PropertyGroup` in my `.csproj` file.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had the *exact* same problem, even down to the Xamarin/Android and Visual Studio versions. This was exactly the solution. Thanks so much!